# Eclipse RCP application with OSGI

Tags: web-services, eclipse-plugin, jax-ws, eclipse-rcp, osgi

I have several web service written formerley and deployed on tomcat. Now I am to develop a new UI with eclipse RCP ( Old SWT application is a little bit redundat). I must make a chooice. I'll use this web service directly with jax-ws client or I'll use OSGI to wrap this service and use this structure via OSGI. Which solution do you suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose your webservices as OSGi services.  This keeps a nice separation between implementation details and the consumer (the UI).

This make it easy if you decide to change the web service to some other type of service (straight servlet calls for instance), and more importantly, trivial to mock your services for developing/testing the new UI.